# Sharing between models of database table variables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm wanting to figure out how the best way to do this is.

I have about 6 different models for my different separated modules and they all share the same variables that I created that hold the values of my database tables. Should I create a special config file that holds these values or is there something better I can do for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a config and pull from that, or you can create a "master" model and extend your other models from that... like this:

```
class Mastermodel extends CI_Model
{
    var $table_name = 'table';          // user accounts
    var $another_table_name = 'another_table';  // user profiles

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    ...
}
```

and then in your other models, change the line

```
class Childmodel extends CI_Model
```

to

```
class Childmodel extends Mastermodel
```

And then you can use `$this->table_name` and `$this->another_table_name` in the child models

By extending the Mastermodel where the variables were instantiated, you inherit those variables.

****It is important to note that you must also load the "master" model otherwise PHP will not have it in memory and can not extend it****

Comment: I did the abovve and it says thtat the mastermodel can not be found.

Comment: Did you load the Mastermodel?